# What is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}_0:=\{A\subset\mathbb{N}\mid A\text{ finite or } A^c \text{ finite}\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}_{0}:=\{A\subset\mathbb{N}\mid A\text{ finite or } A^c \text{ finite}\}$ and $\mu:\mathcal{A}_0\to[0,\infty]$ defined as $\mu(A)=|A|$. Then, what is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}_0$? And, what is the measure obtained by extending $\mu$ on $\mathcal{A}=\sigma(\mathcal{A}_0)$?

The theory that I have learned so far suggests me to construct the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal{A}_0$ but I only know how to do it for a finite collection of subsets. I tried to find a general method on the internet but I couldn't find anything helpful as I am not so versed in the theory of ordinals. But I also found this [article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://math.ecnu.edu.cn/%7Ewsun/teaching/Real_N_Complex_Analysis_2015/An%2520explicit%2520construction%2520of%2520sigma%2520algebra%2520generated%2520by%2520certain%2520sets.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjfg5S2k5z3AhVthv0HHe4zA3oQFnoECAUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1G8B0KzX3-MmoTwmd3Ip1r) helpful but I don't know what the $A_{i,j}$'s are in this case and how to find an extended measure using it.

Could someone help to understand those or is there any simple construction for the $\sigma$-algebra in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every singleton set $\{n\}$ is in $\mathcal A_0$ and every subset of $\mathbb N$ is a countable union of singletons. Hence, $\mathcal A$ is the power set of $\mathbb N$. By countable additivity of measures it follows that the extended measure has $\mu (A)=|A|$ if $A$ is a finite set and $+\infty$ if $A$ is an infinite set. This is the so-called counting measure on $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response!